# phonegap in ios simulator always displays popup

Tags: ios, cordova

basically i gave my html + css + javascript code to my friend, asking him to compile it for phonegap in iOS. the same code works perfectly for android. however he said that everytime he compiled the code, popups will be displayed

here's the pop-up that he meant:

[image]

and

[image]

how do i remove those pop-ups?

Comment: can those who rated-down this question please do tell me why?

Comment: Are you using the correct cordova.js file for iOS?

Comment: @codemonkey could be it! I'd ask my friend who I asked to compile it on IOS to confirm..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, read the comment from codemonkey and discovered that in my html files, I was referring to an old cordova javascript file.

I replaced

```
<script src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

with

```
    <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
```

and the popups disappeared :)